# Updtated titlle: Scipy.stats pdf bug?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy.stats

I have a simple plot of a 2D Gaussian distribution.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

means = [ 1.03872615e+00, -2.66927843e-05]
cov_matrix =  [[3.88809050e-03, 3.90737359e-06], [3.90737359e-06, 4.28819569e-09]]

# This works
a_lims = [0.7, 1.3]
b_lims = [-5, 5]

# This does not work
a_lims = [0.700006488869478, 1.2849292618191401]
b_lims =[-5.000288311285968, 5.000099437047633]

dist = multivariate_normal(mean=means, cov=cov_matrix)
a_plot, b_plot = np.mgrid[a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:1e-2, b_lims[0]:b_lims[1]:0.1]
pos = np.empty(a_plot.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = a_plot
pos[:, :, 1] = b_plot
z = dist.pdf(pos)

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(a_plot, b_plot, z, cmap='coolwarm',  levels=100)
```

If I use the limits marked as "this works", I get the following plot (correct).

[image]

However, if I use the same limits, but slightly adjusted, it plots completely wrong, because localized at different values (below).

[image]

I guess it is a bug in `mgrid`. Does anyone have any ideas? More specifically, why does the maximum of the distribution move?

Comment: Simpler way to make `pos`: `pos = np.dstack(np.mgrid[a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:1e-2, b_lims[0]:b_lims[1]:0.1])`

Comment: Also, the bug is not in `mgrid` you can verify that by showing that the grid is generated correctly every time, which it is

Comment: The bug *appears* to be in the PDF function. Not it its implementation, but in your usage. I think it's a bit suspicious that you aren't seeing any rotation in the ellipse of the Gaussian for that covariance matrix

Comment: I'm not sure the first plot is correct either. The x-mean looks like it's more than half way between 1.0 and 1.1 towards 1.1, maybe 1.06 or 1.07, definitely not 1.038.

Comment: Your X and Y are swapped. A is rows (y), B is columns (X)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Pardon me, I am not sure I understand. I have also thought about the swap, but then the spread would also swap axes: I would see large spread along `b` but I do not. The spread is along `a` as expected. So the axes do not seem to be swapped.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree, the mean in the first plot is not at the correct location either.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And if you believe they are swapped, could you provide the correct piece of code that would correct for the swap?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't figured out the problem. It's definitely not mgrid though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, by increasing the vertical resolution substantially, I get a nice tilted ellipse, centered on the `mean`.

Answer (score 4):

Focusing just on the `xaxis`:

```
In [443]: a_lims = [0.7, 1.3] 
In [444]: np.mgrid[a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:1e-2]                                                   
Out[444]: 
array([0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ,
       0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91,
       0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.  , 1.01, 1.02,
       1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1 , 1.11, 1.12, 1.13,
       1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2 , 1.21, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24,
       1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.3 ])
In [445]: a_lims = [0.700006488869478, 1.2849292618191401]                                     
In [446]: np.mgrid[a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:1e-2]                                                   
Out[446]: 
array([0.70000649, 0.71000649, 0.72000649, 0.73000649, 0.74000649,
       0.75000649, 0.76000649, 0.77000649, 0.78000649, 0.79000649,
       0.80000649, 0.81000649, 0.82000649, 0.83000649, 0.84000649,
       0.85000649, 0.86000649, 0.87000649, 0.88000649, 0.89000649,
       0.90000649, 0.91000649, 0.92000649, 0.93000649, 0.94000649,
       0.95000649, 0.96000649, 0.97000649, 0.98000649, 0.99000649,
       1.00000649, 1.01000649, 1.02000649, 1.03000649, 1.04000649,
       1.05000649, 1.06000649, 1.07000649, 1.08000649, 1.09000649,
       1.10000649, 1.11000649, 1.12000649, 1.13000649, 1.14000649,
       1.15000649, 1.16000649, 1.17000649, 1.18000649, 1.19000649,
       1.20000649, 1.21000649, 1.22000649, 1.23000649, 1.24000649,
       1.25000649, 1.26000649, 1.27000649, 1.28000649])
In [447]: _444.shape                                                                           
Out[447]: (61,)
In [449]: _446.shape                                                                           
Out[449]: (59,)
```

`mgrid` when given ranges like `a:b:c` uses `np.arange(a, b, c)`.  `arange` when given float step is not reliable with regards to the end point.

`mgrid` lets you use `np.linspace` which is better for floating point steps.  For example with the first set of limits:

```
In [453]: a_lims = [0.7, 1.3]                                                                  
In [454]: np.mgrid[a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:61j]                                                    
Out[454]: 
array([0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ,
       0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91,
       0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.  , 1.01, 1.02,
       1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1 , 1.11, 1.12, 1.13,
       1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2 , 1.21, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24,
       1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.3 ])
```

===

By narrowing the `b_lims` considerably, and generating a finer mesh, I get a nice tilted ellipse.

```
means = [ 1, 0]
a_lims = [0.7, 1.3]
b_lims = [-.0002,.0002]

dist = multivariate_normal(mean=means, cov=cov_matrix)
a_plot, b_plot = np.mgrid[ a_lims[0]:a_lims[1]:1001j, b_lims[0]:b_lims[1]:1001j]
```

So I think the difference in your plots is an artifact of an excessively coarse mesh in the vertical direction.  That potentially affects both the `pdf` generation and the contouring.

[image: higher resolution plot]

[image: plot with original grid pts]

High resolution plot with original grid points.  Only one `b` level intersects with the high probability values.  Since the ellipse is tilted the two grids sample different parts, and hence the seemingly different pdfs.

Comment: Right, thank you. But how is the end point in any way related to the mean of the distribution? As long as the shapes are consistent, it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: I haven't tried to follow the logic of the pdf distribution.  I haven't used `multivariate_normal`.  Of hand I wouldn't expect a change, but ...

Comment: Right, but my question is not how to make an array of points of a given shape, but why does the plot look different? The mesh you propose is still a mesh within the same interval. I agree with the point of more control over your points though.

Comment: When I do a simplied 1d case, the plots are nearly identical, `plt.plot(_444, dist.pdf(_444)) ` etc.  Best I can guess is that your `means` has some how changed between the two plots.

Comment: I started with a fresh console between runs, and was able to reproduce the result. I don't think `means` is the problem

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes his difference is reproducible.  I playing around with the `cov` matrix, to see if that's making a difference.  Failing that I'll read the `multivariate_nomal` docs. :)

Comment: @hpaulj. I came to the same conclusion. Definitely can't be `mgrid` based on what I'm seeing

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I am starting to suspect that the bug is in `dist.pdf`. I don't see how `means` could change between the runs. And when I call `dist.mean()` on the incorrect case, it still returns the correct mean: `[ 1.03872615e+00 -2.66927843e-05]`. So the mean is correct, but the `pdf` is wrong.

Comment: @Dr_Z. Looks like the issue is just with the contour, since pdf and mgrid are much simpler and more straightforward/unambiguous.

Comment: I've added a plot that shows where your original grid points lie on the high resolution pdf.  The reason for difference in contour plots becomes obvious - the two grids sample different parts of a tilted ellipse. @MadPhysicist

Comment: This is a nice example of broken abstraction. The explanation is so simple when you delve into it, but it took some thinking to get there.